# Mapper Parsing Exception in Logstash and ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am getting Mapper Parsing Exception while trying to parse logs using Logstash and outputting to ElasticSearch with error message: "field name can not contain dot (.)"

This was working fine with old Logstash version and I have recently upgraded to Logstash 2.0:

My Logstash config file looks like:

```
input {
  kafka {
    topic_id => "topic1"
    zk_connect => "111.222.333.444:2181"
    type => "log_type"
    reset_beginning => true
  }
}

output {
#  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
    flush_size => 200
    idle_flush_time => 1
    index => "index-name-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified on https://discuss.elastic.co/t/field-name-cannot-contain/33251/5, field names can not support dots in their names.

As specified on the page, an easy fix will be to replace all dots with underscores using following filter:

```
filter {
  ruby {
        code => "
          event.to_hash.keys.each { |k| event[ k.sub('.','_') ] = event.remove(k) if k.include?'.' }
        "
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, instead of cleaning up their own code, they introduced a de_dot filter that does this.  https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-the-de_dot-filter